# Elastic search - Control threads based on users

Tags: multithreading, elasticsearch, user-management

I would like to setup the common bigger environment for Elastic search. So that all the projects will use the common elastic search.

My concern here that, I don't how to restrict the thread access based on user/service. So that heavy usage of one project will not affect another project.

Please let me do we have any option to manage threads based on projects.